# Array within array using foreach loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter framework. I am making an array within array and within array using foreach loop for getting record from 3 tables. I have make like this way array

```
Array
(
[devices] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [device_name] => Smartphone
                [device_image] => device-images/1d57a675edbb2ff97c5bc35fce27517c.png
                [device_icon] => device-images/325af5a3587cdfc8f35ae345a2d432a3.png
                [all_manufacturers] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 1
                                [fk_device_id] => 1
                                [manufacture] => Apple
                                [models] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 1
                                                [fk_deviceid] => 1
                                                [fk_manufactureid] => 1
                                                [model_name] =>  iPhone 11 Pro Max 
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 2
                                                [fk_deviceid] => 1
                                                [fk_manufactureid] => 1
                                                [model_name] =>  iPhone 11 Pro 
                                            )

                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 3
                                                [fk_deviceid] => 1
                                                [fk_manufactureid] => 1
                                                [model_name] => iPhone 11
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 2
                                [fk_device_id] => 1
                                [manufacture] => Samsung
                                [models] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 3
                                [fk_device_id] => 1
                                [manufacture] => huawei
                                [models] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 5
                                [fk_device_id] => 1
                                [manufacture] => Sony
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [device_name] => Tablet
                [device_image] => device-images/fd9e3f3192547a89c07e30fbcb7e202b.png
                [device_icon] => device-images/9f39fb4583174c71e3b7f92ec3e5ed86.png
                [all_manufacturers] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 6
                                [fk_device_id] => 2
                                [manufacture] => Apple
                                [models] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 4
                                                [fk_deviceid] => 2
                                                [fk_manufactureid] => 6
                                                [model_name] => iPad 3 (2012)
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 6
                                                [fk_deviceid] => 2
                                                [fk_manufactureid] => 6
                                                [model_name] => iPad 2 (2011)
                                            )

                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 7
                                                [fk_deviceid] => 2
                                                [fk_manufactureid] => 6
                                                [model_name] => iPad 4 (2012)
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 7
                                [fk_device_id] => 2
                                [manufacture] => Microsoft
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [device_name] => Laptop
                [device_image] => device-images/60042e62d2fa440d3c467114538a1293.png
                [device_icon] => device-images/2044d96ba9274b5b1e3155103fa90506.png
                [all_manufacturers] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 11
                                [fk_device_id] => 3
                                [manufacture] => Apple
                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [device_name] => Watch
                [device_image] => device-images/8f10aad91a793372e50a3275db132e4e.png
                [device_icon] => device-images/788dc55b9b6e0f805d63a42fd888e1bb.png
                [all_manufacturers] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 9
                                [fk_device_id] => 4
                                [manufacture] => Apple
                            )

                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6
                [device_name] => Camera
                [device_image] => device-images/88929629884491fd080505b56f1b2b0d.png
                [device_icon] => device-images/88fa1d78fe127e757c1cfc90ec925a14.png
            )

    )
   )
```

**Issue in view page because showing notice error of Undefined index: all_manufacturers**
view page code is below

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="sidebar">
       <?php if($devices) { 
            foreach($devices as $dkey => $device) { 
              $all_manufacturers = $device["all_manufacturers"];?>
                <div class="dropdown cust-dropdown">
                 <button class="btn-dropdown cust-btn-dropdown" type="button"><div class="box-shop-icons"><img src="<?= base_url('assets/uploads/'.$device["device_icon"])?>" ></div>
                 <?= $device['device_name']?>
                 </button>
                 <div class="dropdown-menu-custom">
                 <div class="radio-btns cust-height">
                  <!-- inner radio button -->
                    <?php if ($all_manufacturers) {
                       foreach ($all_manufacturers as $manufacture) { ?>
                         <div class="dropdown">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><?= $manufacture['manufacture']?>
                          <span class="caret"></span></button>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">iPhone 11 pro max</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">iPhone 11 pro</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">iPhone 11</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">iPhone Xs max</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">iPhone Xs</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">iPhone X</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">iPhone 8plus</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>
             <?php } } ?> 
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 <?php } } ?> 
</div>
```

These 3 tables are linked with eachother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last array doesn't have "all_manufacturers" set on it, so the error is that you are trying to set $all_manufacturers without checking if it is set or not.

Remove this line at the top of the loop for devices:

```
$all_manufacturers = $device["all_manufacturers"];
```

Then change this code:

```
<?php if ($all_manufacturers) {
    foreach ($all_manufacturers as $manufacture) { ?>
```

To this:

```
if (!empty($device["all_manufacturers"])) {
    foreach ($device["all_manufacturers"] as $manufacture) {
```

Comment: This modification makes me happy and working perfectly now

Comment: It looks like you need to create one more loop inside the `all_manufacturers` loop so that you can get to `model_name`. Use the same approach where you check if `models` is set for a manufacturer, then create a foreach loop for it. Inside that new loop you should be able to output the `model_name`.

Comment: Yeah i did fellow same approach so now it's working